# angular-js ng-paginate with filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

So I am using ng-paginate for pagination, but there is a slight problem when I use the filter. So I have a dropdown with 3 options.

so when I choose an option from the dropdown the data is filtered but only the data of the page.
Example I have 100 records and I am showing 10 records each page only the data from the 10 records are filtered. 
So I am looking for a solution where the filter should work for all the records, not only from the current page.
here is the code its in jade.

```
<label for="exampleSelect1">Vehicle-Mode
  <select id="exampleSelect1" name="opt" value="opt" ng-model="check" ng-change="getValue(check, fromDate, toDate)" class="form-control">
    <option>Booked</option>
    <option>checked_in</option>
  </select>
</label>
<tr dir-paginate="vehicle in vehicles | filter:search | itemsPerPage:1000">
  <td>{{xxx}}</td>
  <td>{{yyy}}</td>
</tr>
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="1000" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code? Specifically I need to see what `vehicles` is populated with, what happens on `ng-change` and where `search` is set as an object or value.

Comment: @MatthewCawley in my controller I am just making an http call and assigning the result to $scope.vehicles. something like.  $http.get('/getvehicles').then(function(data){  $scope.vehicles = data; })   // where data is an array of vehicles

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was in their documentation
Frequently Asked Questions

Why does my sort / filter only affect the current page?

This is a common problem and is usually due to the itemsPerPage filter not being at the end of the expression. For example, consider the following:

```
<li dir-paginate="item in collection | itemsPerPage: 10 | filter: q">...</li> <!-- BAD -->
```

In this case, the collection is first truncated to 10 items by the itemsPerPage filter, and then those 10 items only are filtered. The solution is to ensure the itemsPerPage filter comes after any sorting / filtering:

```
<li dir-paginate="item in collection | filter: q | itemsPerPage: 10">...</li> <!-- GOOD -->
```